# Problem with using serilog log file in C++ native code of WPF app

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, serilog

We have a WPF app using Serilog for logging. When we try to open the file in a C++ dll we are getting an error. GetLastError returns "file in use by another process". The aim is to have the C+ code and C# code writing to the same log file. We have checked if we change the name of the file in C++ we get a a log file created in the same directory as where the WPF log file is. The C++ code is loaded into the same process so not sure why there is an issue with doing this.

```
      ILoggerFactory loggerFactory = new LoggerFactory();
            var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(path)
                .AddJsonFile("logging.json")
                .Build();

        string logpath = System.IO.Path.Combine($"{Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)}", "log.txt");
       var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
                        .MinimumLevel.Information()
                     .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
                    .Enrich.FromLogContext().WriteTo.File(logpath, shared: true).CreateLogger();

            loggerFactory.AddSerilog(log);
```

Logging.json

```
             {
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.Debug", "Serilog.Sinks.RollingFile" ],
    "MinimumLevel": {
        "Default": "Information"
      
    },
    "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ],
    "WriteTo": [
        { "Name": "Debug" },
        {
            "Name": "File",
          "Args": {
            "path": "%APPDATA%\\log.txt"

          }
        }
    ],
    "Properties": {
        "Application": "app"
    }
}
```

}

trying to access it in a C++ dll

```
           std::ofstream* ofs = new std::ofstream(logFileName.c_str(), std::ios_base::out |  std::ios_base::app));
          if (ofs->is_open())
          {
              // the is_open call fails so we don't get here
              std::cout << "Operation successfully performed\n";
           }
```

Answer (score 0):

> The aim is to have the C+ code and C# code writing to the same log file.

The operating system locks the file so only one process at a time can open it for writing.

Writing concurrently and reliably to a single file means that you need to synchronize the access to it from your processes, for example using a mutex. Each process should then acquire the mutex, open the file stream, write to the file and then close the stream.

A better idea would be probably to have a file per process and then merge them together when needed, for example at the end of each day or something.